# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ using the integral test

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Given the series : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{n}}$$ **Determine if convergent or divergent.**

The function is positive and monotonically decreasing function so I've used the "Integral Test"

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}}$$

then:$$ e^{-\sqrt{x}}\leq e^{\sqrt{x}}\leq e^{x}$$

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{x}dx$$ which is clearly **Divergent** but the answer for some reason is **convergent**

Edit: Sorry for the misinterpretation. I forgot that if $f(x)>g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is divergent, it doesn't necessarily mean that $g(x)$ is divergent(contrary to convergent). **Does anyone have a general direction for how do I suppose to solve it?** I think that integral test is the most natural direction for solving this

Comment: You replaced your integral with something much larger.  You can't conclude anything about the convergence or divergence of your integral.

Comment: You say, about your original function "The function is positive and monotonically decreasing", and then compare it to a monotonically increasing function $e^x$? Why?

Comment: @YuriyS thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ProgC, you are welcome, hope the answers in this thread were helpful

Answer (score 15):

$u=\sqrt x;\ du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}dx\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int_{1}^{\infty}ue^{-u}du $ and this integral converges.

Answer (score 10):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, $e^{-\sqrt n}\leqslant\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt n}$. But the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt n}$ converges, by the integral test:$$\int_1^\infty\sqrt xe^{-\sqrt x}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\bigl[-\left(2x+4\sqrt x+4\right)e^{-\sqrt x}\bigr]_1^M=\frac 6e.$$Therefore, your series converges, too.

Answer (score 6):

Hint.

$$
\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt n}}\le \frac{1}{e^{1.2\ln n}} = \frac{1}{n^{1.2}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

I usually think that Integral Test is the least elegant way to show the convergence of a sequence. I do have to admit that it is convenient, simple and powerful, though.

In order to show convergence of series involving negative power of $e$, using the Taylor Expansion of $e^x$ is a good way.

Notice that

$$e^\sqrt{n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{n})^k}{k!} > \frac{n^2}{4!}$$

we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^\sqrt{n}} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4!}{n^2} $$

and then you should be able to prove that the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Near $+\infty$, $\;n^2=o\bigl(\mathrm e^{\sqrt n}\bigr)$, whence $\;\mathrm e^{-\sqrt n}=o\Bigl(\dfrac1{n^2}\Bigr)$.

Comment: what those little zeros mean?

Comment: It's *little oh* (not $0$), used in asymptotic analysis. Roughly speaking, $f=o(g)$ means the ratio $\dfrac fg$ tends to $0$ at $\infty$.

Comment: Ohhh but this To me it is too fancy and probably to the question guy too lol, see jose answer o matematleta answer

Comment: Maybe it's fancy, but it's standard and very short. The result (not the notations,  of course) is known from high school.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth knowing that the $2$ can be any $p>1$. As in, the series converges faster than any $p$-series does.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the sandwich/squeeze theorem with the integral test.

The sandwich theorem says that if $g_1(x)<f(x)<g_2(x)$ and $g_1$ and $g_2$ converge, then $f$ converges. The converse does not hold: if $g_1$ and $g_2$ diverge, that does not mean that $f$ diverges. If the converse were true, then any function that is smaller than $e^x$ would be divergent, which is absurd.

The *integral* test, on the other hand, is an "if and only if" test, but that just takes the integral of the sequence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence . So you should take just the integral of $e^{\sqrt x}$, not $e^{-\sqrt x}$ or $e^{x}$